# Error with apturl in Ubuntu

Tags: apturl

I was attempting to use playdeb/getdeb and it wasn't working. So I went to the terminal to see what was happening. The problem is I have no idea what this actually means or how to fix it. Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

```
~$ apturl apt:enemy-territoy
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/GtkUI.py:1: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk

(apturl-gtk:11037): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:90:44: Failed to import: Error opening file: No such file or directory
ERROR:root:importing aptdaemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in get_backend
    from .InstallBackendAptdaemon import InstallBackendAptdaemon
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 10, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.backend import InstallBackend
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Dialogs import Dialog
ImportError: No module named 'UpdateManager.Dialogs'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apturl-gtk", line 43, in <module>
    ui = GtkUI()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/GtkUI.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.backend = get_backend(self.dia)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/backend/__init__.py", line 48, in get_backend
    from .InstallBackendSynaptic import InstallBackendSynaptic
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/AptUrl/gtk/backend/InstallBackendSynaptic.py", line 12, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.backend import InstallBackend
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Dialogs import Dialog
ImportError: No module named 'UpdateManager.Dialogs'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled `apturl` to solve it.

```
sudo apt-get remove apturl apturl-common

sudo apt-get install apturl apturl-common
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked with purge instead of remove

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager python3-update-manager
```

The python module was missing. Seems to be a dependency bug in Ubuntu 18.04